# Cannot create release from build - DEVOPS

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-pipelines

Since a few days, I cannot create a release from a complished build in devops... there was an option to create a release from a specific build, on the three points button on the top-rigth corner of the screen. But this option has gone!!

As shown in the picture:

[image]

I have been experimenting also some 404 errors like "Build not found" when if you reload page it really exists the build. But I dont know if are the same cause...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The option has been moved right now. You cannot get that by that interface.

And you have to use the option from the main interface under **Pipeline**-->**Release.**

[image]

You could use that to create a new release automatically after the build pipeline.

Here is [a document about the guidance](https://itnext.io/azure-devops-releases-auto-create-new-release-after-pipeline-build-ac03d21f726e).

Comment: Thanks Perry, but what i am looking for is to release an especfic build, not the last one. Lets say you have run 10 builds and you want to release the fifth build. How can you do that?

Comment: And the artifact under Release could select the specific pipeline name. You could select the one to generate the related new release automatically. See [this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unejF.png).